# Php get specific array in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a solution to get an array from a multidimensional array

For example; This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Laïla Mertens 
            [text] => Laïla Mertens 
            [parent_id] => 
            [href] => http://google.com
            [nodes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Erwin Dubois
                            [text] => Erwin Dubois
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [name] => Test Gebruiker
                                            [text] => Test Gebruiker
                                            [parent_id] => 1
                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [name] => Catharina
                                            [text] => Catharina
                                            [parent_id] => 1
                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => Araxanta
                            [text] => Araxanta
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 15
                                            [name] => Kevin
                                            [text] => Kevin
                                            [parent_id] => 5
                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                            [nodes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 16
                                                            [name] => Petra
                                                            [text] => Petra
                                                            [parent_id] => 15
                                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 17
                                                            [name] => Shannah
                                                            [text] => Shannah
                                                            [parent_id] => 15
                                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [name] => Christian
                            [text] => Christian
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 13
                                            [name] => Macy VanMaele
                                            [text] => Macy VanMaele
                                            [parent_id] => 6
                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14
                                            [name] => April Poizat
                                            [text] => April Poizat
                                            [parent_id] => 6
                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                            [nodes] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 7
                                                            [name] => Sigrid
                                                            [text] => Sigrid
                                                            [parent_id] => 14
                                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [name] => Nikita
                            [text] => Nikita
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [name] => Salina Lemmens
                            [text] => Salina Lemmens
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [name] => Emmily Polen
                            [text] => Emmily Polen
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [name] => Jitka Symus
                            [text] => Jitka Symus
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [name] => Amina Gigovic
                            [text] => Amina Gigovic
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I'd like to get the array where the id equals 1

So in this example, where [id] => 1 I would like to capture the entire array of id 1, thus:

```
Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Erwin Dubois
                            [text] => Erwin Dubois
                            [parent_id] => 2
                            [href] => http://google.com
                            [nodes] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [name] => Test Gebruiker
                                            [text] => Test Gebruiker
                                            [parent_id] => 1
                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [name] => Catharina
                                            [text] => Catharina
                                            [parent_id] => 1
                                            [href] => http://google.com
                                        )

                                )

                        )
```

Is there a way in php where I can have a function like;

```
function get_subarray($id) {
  // Select array where id = $id
}
```

Any point towards the direction is greatly appreciated!
It would be needed into a function since I would parse different userlevels depending on their unique id

array:

```
$json = file_get_contents("https://innerbeauthe.be/cp/_data/fetch.php");
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

Comment: Is there guaranteed to be only one of any given `id`?

Comment: Yes, the id is a unique identifier (PK, UQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a recursive function which traverses the array in search of the desired array key.

Although PHP includes a function `array_walk_recursive()`, it will traverse into leaf nodes and makes it difficult to return a parent array. Likewise, using `RecursiveArrayIterator` actually complicates getting at the array you want instead of the leaf notes. Instead it is not too complicated to create your own:

```
// Function accepts an array and a search value
function walk_for_array(array $a, $search) {
  // Loop over the array
  foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    // Find sub-arrays (rather than scalar values)
    if (is_array($v)) {
      // Check if there is an 'id' key and if it matches your search value
      if (isset($v['id']) && $v['id'] == $search) {                                                                                           
        // return it
        return $v; 
      }   
      else {
        // Otherwise continue drilling into the array for more arrays
        $sub = walk_for_array($v, $search);
        // Return the recursive value only if the inner call
        // was non-null
        if ($sub) return $sub;
      }   
    }   
  }
}

// Call it, searching for id == 1
$found = walk_for_array($your_big_array, 1);

print_r($found);

// Call it, searching for id == 13
$found = walk_for_array($your_big_array, 13);

print_r($found);
```

#### Prints:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Erwin Dubois
    [text] => Erwin Dubois
    [parent_id] => 2
    [href] => http://google.com
    [nodes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Test Gebruiker
                    [text] => Test Gebruiker
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [href] => http://google.com
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Catharina
                    [text] => Catharina
                    [parent_id] => 1
                    [href] => http://google.com
                )

        )

)
```

#### And for id = 13

```
Array
(
    [id] => 13
    [name] => Macy VanMaele
    [text] => Macy VanMaele
    [parent_id] => 6
    [href] => http://google.com
)
```

Comment: Hello Michael,

Thank you for your response, 
I tried the function you posted and it worked for the following id's:

1 & 2; 

If for example, I would select Id = 5, I get no results at all, tried to break down the function in printable arrays but don't see why it doesn't load the id 5 nor the others (3 for example)

Comment: I will have some time to look at it in a couple of hours.

Comment: @ErwinDubois Okay I think it's working correctly now - the recursive array call was passing through its return even if null. That is fixed to continue searching until the inner call returns a non-null

Comment: Thank you! It works like a charm, you saved me hours of head scratching, eye frowning, table-bashing arguements with myselve! haha.

Greatly appreciated, also I love the fact that you commented out the function, gives me the time to see the logic in it.

Comment: You're welcome. With regard to commenting the function, if someone posts an answer for to your question without good explanation, please don't be afraid to ask them for an explanation with a comment. While I have certainly encountered individuals here who bristle at that, the explanations are much more valuable to future searchers who find the answer.